# Javascript Animation on scroll, Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I want to use this code that i have seen on github, but I don't know how to apply this code on my HTML, to have an scrolling effect.

The point is, I don't know how to run use this code

source https://gist.github.com/andjosh/6764939

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function () {
    scrollTo(document.body, 0, 1250); 
}

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        currentTime = 0,
        increment = 20;

    var animateScroll = function(){        
        currentTime += increment;
        var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
        element.scrollTop = val;
        if(currentTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
        }
    };
    animateScroll();
}

//t = current time
//b = start value
//c = change in value
//d = duration
Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d/2;
    if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    t--;
    return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
};
```

Comment: Do you have a ```<button>``` element in your HTML? What happens when you click it?

Comment: I tried it bro, but nothing happens.

Comment: anyone can provide an example? On how this works. It will be a great help

Comment: Voting to close because you do not include the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to replace `document.body` with `document.documentElement`, <s>as `document.body.scrollTop()` has been deprecated.</s>

**Edit:** it seems that I was not completely right about document.body.scrollTop() being deprecated. The best solution to support multiple browsers is to check for both cases.

Second, you need to set a value > 0 for the 'to' parameter, as Quantastical already pointed out.

Also make sure you have a `<button>` element. It should work then.

Comment: You are still querying for the body with `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` replace it with just `document.documentElement` and it works.

Comment: Thanks broooo, great help for a newbie like me :)

Comment: You're welcome :) It's good to know: `document.documentElement` will return <html> not <body>.

Comment: Why it is not working with document.body? I don't know what's the difference, I want to learn :)

Comment: It's a bit of a browser specific issue. Some browsers attach the scrollbar to the global window object in other words, the document.documentElement (= <html> tag). Others browsers attach it to the document.body (= <body> tag). This causes lots of confusion, search for it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Also in my answer I said that document.body.scrolTop() has been depricated, but this is not completely true. Most browsers will work with the document.documentElement, but there are still cases where document.body just works. Best solution is to test for both in an if / else for example.